# Why C++ std::function pass the functor by value instead of universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, generics

The constructor of std::function looks like this (at least in libc++):

```cpp
namespace std {

template<class _Rp, class ..._ArgTypes>
function {
  // ...
  base_func<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)> __func;

public:
  template<typename _Fp>
  function(_Fp __f) : __func(std::move(__f)) {}

  template<typename _Fp>
  function& operator=(_Fp&& __f) {
    function(std::forward<_Fp>(__f)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }
};

}
```

It provides a constructor from an arbitrary functor and an assignment operator from an arbitrary functor. The constructor uses pass-by-value but the assignment operator uses pass-by-universal-reference.

My question is why the constructor of std::function doesn't pass by universal (forwarding) reference in the same way as the assignment operator? For example, it could do:

```cpp
namespace std {

template<class _Rp, class ..._ArgTypes>
function {
  // ...
  base_func<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)> __func;
public:
  template<typename _Fp>
  function(_Fp&& __f) : __func(std::forward<_Fp>(__f)) {}
  
  template<typename _Fp>
  function& operator=(_Fp&& __f) {
    function(std::forward<_Fp>(__f)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }
};

}
```

I am curious what the rationale behind treating assignment and constructor differently here. Thanks!

Comment: Because [that's what the language specification requires](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/func.wrap.func). Note that your example is flawed because you don't have a move constructor, so the only choice is to copy. If you add `Func(Func&& f) { std::cout << "move ctor is called" << std::endl; }` then you'll see that it gets moved.

Comment: If you take look at any standard library function that takes a callable argument, you will see that they all take these argument by value.

Comment: your last edit makes the question invalid. And you are missing a default constructor too. : https://godbolt.org/z/3K7MoE Can not reproduce it anymore!

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for the answer. I realized that my question did not make sense after multiple edits. I also realized that passing-by-value can also avoid copying if done correctly. I have revised the question.

Answer (score 5):

That is what it's called a "sink parameter". A *sink parameter* is a parameter of a method that needs to be "taken" from the caller and stored in the object (as a data member). The caller usually doesn't need/use the the object after the call.

The best practice for a sink parameter is to pass it by value and move from it into the object. Let's see why:

## Option 1: pass by reference

```
class X; // expensive to copy type with cheap move

struct A
{
     X stored_x_;

     A(const X& x) : x_{x} {}
//                   ^~~~~
//                   this is always a copy
};
```

In this case there will always be at least 1 copy that cannot be elided.

## Option 2: pass by value and then move from

```
class X; // expensive to copy type with cheap move

struct A
{
     X stored_x_;

     A(X x) : x_{std::move(x)} {}
//            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//            this is now a move
};
```

We got rid of the move in the initialization of `A::x_`, but we still have a copy on passing the parameter, or do we?

If the caller does the right thing we don't. We have two cases here: The caller still needs a copy of the object passed (which is pretty unusual and non-idiomatic). In this case yes, a copy will be made, but that is because the called requires that, not because of a flaw in the design of our class `A`.

The caller doesn't need the object after passing it. In this case it moves the argument or better yet passes a prvalue and since C++17 with the new temporary materialization rules the object is created directly as a parameter:

### Pass an xvalue

```
auto test()
{
    X x{};

    A a{std::move(x)}; // 2 moves (from arg to parameter and from parameter to `A::x_`)
};
```

### Pass an prvalue

```
auto test()
{
    A a{X{}}; // just the move in the initialization of `A::x_`
}
```

## Option 3: lvalue and rvalue reference overloads

Yes, this will achieve the same level of performance, but why have 2 overloads when you can write and maintain just 1 method.

```
class X; // expensive to copy type with cheap move

struct A
{
     X stored_x_;

     A(const X& x) : x_{x} {}
     A(X&& x) : x_{std::move(x)} {}
};
```

Unneeded complexity which blows out when you have multiple *sink parameters* in 1 method.

## Option 4: pass by forwarding reference:

Again, possible. But it can have some subtle but pretty serios problems:

- if you don't have a template parameter then you need to make it a template, which adds complexity and also adds other problems like now the method accepts **any** type.
- This is even worse for a constructor as now this constructor is a viable option for a copy constructor which can really mess things up because this will be a better fit for a copy from a non-const object.

Another problem is that it cannot be always used:

- if you want to accept any type that is not simply `T`, e.g. if `X` is templated: `template <class T> A(X<T>&& x)` this is not a forwarding reference, but an rvalue reference and you need an lvalue reference overload.